# SET-ACL Issue when setting permisisons on anything but C: Drive on 1 particular server

Tags: powershell, server, acl, windows-server-2012-r2, drive

Im after some help with an issue that is driving me slightly mad.

Basically we have a large internal developed User tools system and 1 function of this is to create user accounts, create the home folder structure and assign the user permissions to this.  This toolset works across 10 or so domains and multiple file servers (some domains it can have 70 individual customers with local file servers it interacts with...) all works great has done for  along time.

The scripts are run on a utility server that has access to all the domains and is run by semi-privileged accounts - not domain admin or Ent Admins.On 1 of the domains i can not get it to work unless the user account/group that is used to run the code is an administrator on the FileServer - it is not setup like this anywhere else and the permissions on the folders are the same everywhere.

The only way it works on this server is on the C drive, it will not work against any other drive volume (D, E etc..) All of the NTFS and share permisisons are exaclty the same (copied from the actual real share to the test share on root of C)

A snippet of the code is below and the assumtion is that share is on the **D** drive....:

```
           #Share Location
           $userpath = "\\Server1\TEST\Test.User10"


           $NewUser = get-aduser -Identity Test.User10 -Server MyDomain.local -Properties * | Select SID
           #Folders
            #$userPath = $creationSite.homePath+"\"+$userUsername
            $userSID = $newUser.SID

            Write-Host "Creating user folders at: $userPath"
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "Securing for $userSID"
            Write-Host ""
            New-Item "$userPath" -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
            New-Item "$userPath\Documents" -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
            New-Item "$userPath\Desktop" -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
            New-Item "$userPath\Favorites" -ItemType Directory | Out-Null

$acl = Get-Acl $userPath

$FileSystemRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"FullControl"
$AccessControlType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow
$InheritanceFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit"
$PropagationFlags = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]"NONE"

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($userSID, $FileSystemRights, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $AccessControlType)
$acl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule) 
      
     Set-Acl -Path $userPath -AclObject $acl -Verbose
```

This will produce the following error:

```
Set-Acl : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

+ ...         $icaclsRes = Set-Acl -Path $userPath -AclObject $acl -Verbose
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: ("\\Server1\TEST\Test.User10":String) [Set-Acl], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

If i run the above script pointing to a share on the C drive, set with the EXACT same permisisons, folder inheritance etc then it will complete successfully.

Like i say this whole system has been used for a couple of years now across a lot of systems and i;ve not had this as an issue.

Equally if i add the Semi-Privilaged Security group in as a local admin on the File server in question it works fine also.

I've checked all UAC etc and this is all primarily off, but most importantly set the same as all the other servers i have.

Help or advise greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check permissions on share (not on folder, but in share properties) using `net share SHARENAME` or using GUI. 


*Also*: UAC does not works for remote access to share, UAC works only for interactive users (console or terminal).

Comment: All shares, live and 'test' are set to Authenticated Users, Full Control.  Thanks.